# Error while using a divide function in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I comment the line:

```
 average_amount_by_survivor:{$divide: ['$itens.count', countTotal]}
```

My code works, I tried to use the functions Sum and Multiply with 2 or more arguments and dont work too.

```
.get(function(req, res){
    Survivor.count(function(error,countTotal){
        Survivor.aggregate([
            {$unwind: '$itens'},
            {$group:{
                //itens:{$push: '$itens'},
                _id: '$itens.item',
                total_amount:{$sum:'$itens.count'},
                average_amount_by_survivor:{$divide: ['$itens.count', countTotal]}
            }}],
            function(error, result){
                console.log(result);
                console.log(countTotal);
                res.json(result)
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: The variable result stay undefined

Comment: There are only handful of [top operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) allowed in group stage. Also the result of itens.count i.e total_amount is only avaible in next stage. So to fix your problem you can add `{$addFields:{average_amount_by_survivor:{$divide: ['$total_amount', countTotal]}}}` stage after group stage

Comment: Thanks a lot @Veeram solved my problem.